# Find the values so the function is differentiable

Tags: piecewise-continuity

Struggling with this for some reason. I know that you have to check for continuity but I am confusing myself.

> Find the values of a and b so that the following function is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.
>   $$  f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> -3x+a,  & x\ne2 \\
> b, & x=2
> \end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Differentiability is more than continuity. Also, if you are confusing yourself, and would like some help, it probably helps to say what you exactly is confusing you.

Comment: What would you say if you were aiming for continuity?

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ if this Limit exists and $h\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of continuity we have $b=a-6$. In that case $f(x)=-3x+a$ for all real numbers $x$ and everywhere differentiable.